# Run two javascript functions in parallel with promises

Tags: javascript, promise

```
(function() {

  function main() {
    call1();
    call2();
  }

  function call1() {
    return new Promise(() => {
      for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
        console.log('This is call-1:', i);
      }
    });
  }

  function call2() {
    return new Promise(() => {
      for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
        console.log('This is call-2:', i);
      }
    });
  }

  main();

})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NtioG92Tiba1KuKTx24I

The output contains all `call-1` statements followed by all `call-2` statements. I want to run those 2 calls in parallel. This is just an example to mimic my real code where I have 2 functions with ajax calls inside each function. success or failure of those calls with trigger another series of calls. So, I want to those 2 main functions in parallel. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Promises don't make anything run in parallel, they do not introduce multithreading or something. They just help with waiting for things that already have an asynchronous nature - and your example code does not have that, while your real code (with ajax) would. Please show us the ajax code.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. Only one of those loops can run at a time in the main thread. Not entirely clear what you are looking for

Comment: I am not sure, but this may help - https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel

Comment: @psinaught No, it won't. That's not making anything parallel either. And promises are a much better idea than using async.js

Comment: @Bergi I think OP is using "parallel" as an adjective (as does the async library) and not to refer to the parallel execution of threads. And in that sense, yes, Promises to allow things to happen in parallel.

Comment: "This is just an example to mimic my real code where I have 2 functions with ajax calls inside each function." Maybe... use an example that's similarly asynchronous, such as setTimeouts?

Comment: The code you've provided in the question is not equivalent to your actual intent. There's a big difference between a for loop with a synchronous `console.log` call, and your potentially asynchronous AJAX calling code. Your question is unanswerable in its current form. Please read the [mcve] help article, for tips on formulating a good code example.

Comment: No-one seems to have answered your actual question: Yes, this is the right approach. It just looks wrong because you have 2 synchronous functions. It will work fine when they're asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather common misconception about Promises. The Promise constructor (or rather, the function you pass to it) is executed *synchronously* and *immediately*.

The following code:

```
console.log(1);
new Promise(resolve => resolve(console.log(2));
console.log(3);
```

Outputs 1 2 3 in that order, always.

Both of the functions you've passed to both of your Promise constructors are fully synchronous. There's no asynchronous action (like a setTimeout, or reading a file with a callback), so it's executed one, after the other.

*Unlike* what some of the other answers may tell you, `Promise.all()` will not save you in this case. The event loop, or ticks, or any other the other terms you might have heard of do not come into effect. Your code is fully synchronous.

---

Most JavaScript runtimes (browsers, Node.js, etc) are *single threaded*, in that your JavaScript code runs in a single thread (the browser uses many threads, but your JS code runs in one).

So in this particular case, there's nothing you can do (save from using workers or other threading options, which you *probably* don't want to get into). You can't magically make synchronous code asynchronous, even with trickery.

Comment: It was pretty clear this was not the OPs intent for this question. Appreciate the civil discourse on SO as always, though.

Answer (score -1):

Look into `Promise.all` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

This will call all your promises and resolve when they are complete (resolved or rejected).

Another option, depending on your use case, is `Promise.race`.

This will return the first Promise that completes (resolves or rejects) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Answer (score -1):

Actually your two Promise run in same thread.

So you may want [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in
>   background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without
>   interfering with the user interface. In addition, they can perform I/O
>   using XMLHttpRequest (although the responseXML and channel attributes
>   are always null)

Like below demo:

```js
let url1 = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent])
)
let worker1 = new Worker(url1)

let url2 = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker2').textContent])
)
let worker2 = new Worker(url2)

worker1.onmessage = (msg)=>{
  console.log(msg.data)
}

worker2.onmessage = (msg)=>{
  console.log(msg.data)
}

worker1.postMessage('init');
worker2.postMessage('init');
```

```html
<script id="worker1" type="app/worker">
  addEventListener('message', function () { 
    for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
      postMessage('This is call-1: ' + i)
    }
  }, false);
</script>

<script id="worker2" type="app/worker">
  addEventListener('message', function () { 
    for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
      postMessage('This is call-2: ' + i)
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to run your main function like this:

```
function main() {
  Promise.all([call1(), call2()])
    .then( (data) => {
      // this block will run, if and when BOTH calls/promises resolve
      // process the data from calls
    })
    .catch( (err) => { // process the err });
}
```

`Promise.all` is way of how to run 2 and more async calls and wait until ALL of them are completed. As mentioned in comments they are not running parallel as you might think.

Also make sure, that your `call1()` and `call2()` function will call `resolve` or `reject` functions at some point. By calling these functions you let program know whether it is completed or "errored". More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)